# Does a licence for Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview expire?

Tags: windows, upgrade

I have a licencing question regarding Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview 5

I am contemplating which server OS would be the best option for me and a VPS host I've found offers the above as an option.

My question is, does the licence for that server version expire and I have to upgrade once Windows Server 2016 is fully "fledged" and released? Or will my server instance upgrade itself with each technical preview release and then finally to the full release and keep the same licence?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Technical Preview 5 expires December 31, 2016.

found under the preinstall information here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-technical-preview

Comment: Do not feed the trolls.

Comment: I know, aye. this community can be so arrogant and nasty, it's toxic